# Trying to run a python file and having the output take up the entire window (similar to Vim behaviour)

Tags: neovim

To illustrate I have vim and neovim open side by side in tmux, both with splits. I have a file called test.py open with "print("test")" in it, which I want to run.
[image: 3 Splits open in neovim (left), 2 splits open in vim (right)]

then I use the command :! clear; python % on both and it ends up looking like this:
[image: NeoVim runs the command in a small terminal in the bottom (which also shows the clear command characters) while Vim shows the output in a new window]

Vim's output takes up the entire window (the behaviour I want) while NeoVim takes up only a small portion of the bottom of the window.
I've also tried using vim's terminal emulator with the command :terminal python %, but then it only shows the output on top of the current split instead of occupying the entire window. A similar behaviour to what I want would be tabnew +terminal and inside that tab writing python  and then exit, but I can't figure out how to do all that with only one command

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I cant speak to the rest, so I’ll wait if anyone can; in the meantime, try `:tab terminal python %` (using the tab modifier on a command that creates a split)

Comment: I think the desired behavior you're talking about is the altscreen. It seems that since adding support for built-in terminal buffers, Vim and NeoVim no longer use this, and I've never found a way to get it back.